# Conductor: navigate to a Controller without adding it to backstack

Tags: android, conductor

I am implementing some navigation with Conductor library. So basically, from a certain Controller, no matter how far I navigate from it, on the back press, I want to be able to return to it (from any further Controller).
Now I tried to do something like:

```
router.backstack.remove(router.backstackSize)
```

onCreateView for new controller, as I thought, to remove the newly added controller, but that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easy ways to do this is to use something like `router.popToTag(controller.tag())` which will pop any controllers off of the backstack that are on top of the controller.

The other way, if this is going to be the bottom most controller is to use `router.setRoot(...)` in your Activities controller. (`router.hasRootController()` can let you know if this has already been done) Then returning to "home" is just a matter of `router.popToRoot()`